# Guess the driver which never breaks the driving rules?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Guess the driver ??

There is one driver which never goes against the rules. Which driver never breaks the rules or laws of driving ?? Is there any driver you know who did the same ?? Name that specific driver

Comment: It's me playing GTA

Answer (score 4):

> Screwdriver. You can use it just by the rules, otherwise it won't do its job.

Comment: Driving after too many of these definitely breaks the rules of driving, though :)

Comment: @jafe You are quite right. I screw fixed with a hammer holds better than a nail fixed with a screwdriver.